# Meson - How to specify which wxgtk version to use?

Tags: wxwidgets, meson-build

I'm using Arch Linux and working on a project using `wxgtk3` which I installed from `pacman`, I also installed `wxformbuilder` from the `AUR` which pulls in `wxgtk2` as a dependency. When I try to build my program, it builds fine, but when I try to run it, it throws a huge error message,

```
.
.
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxTreebook" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxVListBox" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxVScrolledWindow" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxHScrolledWindow" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxHVScrolledWindow" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?
./src/common/object.cpp(245): assert "classTable->Get(m_className) == NULL" failed in Register(): Class "wxXmlResourceHandler" already in RTTI table - have you used IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS() multiple times or linked some object file twice)?

(SampleHive:26191): Gtk-ERROR **: 05:45:13.924: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported
zsh: trace trap  ./SampleHive
```

this is only a small section of the error..

But if I uninstall `wxgtk2` and try to run my program again, it runs fine. Is there a way to specify in `meson` to always use `wxgtk3`, so I don't have to uninstall `wxgtk2` again and again, as I need `wxformbuilder` installed on my system.

EDIT:

This is my `meson.build` file,

```
project('SampleHive', 'cpp',
  version : '0.1',
  license : 'GPL v3',
  default_options : ['warning_level=1',
                     'cpp_std=c++11'])

src = [

  'src/App.cpp',
  'src/MainFrame.cpp',
  'src/Browser.cpp',
  'src/SettingsDialog.cpp',
  'src/TagEditorDialog.cpp',
  'src/Database.cpp',
  'src/Serialize.cpp',
  'src/TreeItemDialog.cpp',
  'src/Tags.cpp',

  ]

wx = dependency('wxwidgets', modules : ['media', 'std'])
wxsvg = dependency('libwxsvg')
taglib = dependency('taglib')
sqlite3 = dependency('sqlite3')
yaml = dependency('yaml-cpp')

wx_inc = include_directories('/usr/include/wx-3.0')

executable('SampleHive',
           sources : src,
           dependencies : [wx, wxsvg, taglib, sqlite3, yaml],
           include_directories : wx_inc)
```

to build the project I run,

```
meson build
ninja -C build
```

And here is the link to the repository - [SampleHive](https://gitlab.com/apoorv569/sample-hive)

Comment: please show which command you used to build your application.

Comment: @Igor I have updated my original post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked, there is a `wxformbuilder-git` package in the `AUR` that pulls `wxgtk3` instead of `wxgtk2` as the dependency so that should fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify version for your dependency as:

```
some_dep = dependency('some_dep', version : '>=1.2.3')
```

In your case, use :

```
wx = dependency('wxwidgets', modules : ['media', 'std'], version: '>=3.0.0')
```

Comment: Yes, but both `wxgtk3` and `wxgtk2` are same versions, i.e `3.0.5`, I want to specify if it should use `wx-config-gtk3` which is `wxgtk3` or `wx-config` which is `wxgtk2`.

Answer (score 0):

@apporv,

To build your project do:

```
cd <my_project_dir>
g++ -o <my_project_binary_name> *.cpp `/path/to/wx-config/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
```

And then just do:

```
./my_project_binary
```

Very simple and straightforward.

Make sure to use backpacks around wx-config command.

Comment: Yes, but then what is the point of using `meson` then.

Comment: @apoorv569, none whatsoever. Why did you choose it? It is not a compiler and it is not heling to generate a Makefile like `CMake`. Compiling my way is simple and straightforward. And hopefully works. I would understand if you work with an IDE like Anjuta or Eclipse. Or `CMake-crap` to generqate Makefile. But you doing everything from the Terminal by hand anyway. And you are not creating an so file(s).